# Rails time_select specify start and stop hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

Looking to adjust my `time_select` dropdown to only show the hours between a specified range. So right now it is showing **12 AM, 01 AM, 02 AM ...etc** but I only want to be able to have the user select between say, 7 AM and 7 PM. I can not find this information anywhere.

Also, if anyone knows how to remove the leading zero for the hour/minute select that would be really neat to know.

```
<%= f.time_select :job_time, { ampm: true, :minute_step => 15, :time_separator => "" }, { class: 'form-control time-select mb-3' } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass `start_hour` and `end_hour` options:

```
<%= f.time_select :job_time, { start_hour: 7, end_hour: 19, ampm: true, :minute_step => 15, :time_separator => "" } %>
```

Documentation [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L475-L476)